# line breaks in SQL query string from VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am building a command string in VBA to be handed over to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio which looks something like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp   
GO
CREATE TABLE #temp
```

However, the command string in VBA does not include line breaks required for the GO statment which causes the execution to fail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you are building your command string, use `vbCrLf` to create a new line.

Example:

```
Dim strMyCommand As String

strMyCommand = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp" & vbCrLf & _
  "GO" & vbCrLf & _
  "CREATE TABLE #temp"

Debug.Print strMyCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use GO in an sql string, even if separated by carriage returns and line feeds... this is a batch separator only known to SQLCMD and SQL Server Management Studio.
For the above query you have to issue two calls to your database connection.

For instance, this works (on a local SQL Server instance) :

```
Sub test()
    Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
    Set oConn = New Connection
    oConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    oConn.Open
    oConn.Execute "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp"
    oConn.Execute "Create table #temp(somecolumn int)"

    oConn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: _"GO... is a batch separator only known to SQLCMD and SQL Server Management Studio."_ This was my initial thought too. Then I re-read fboehlandt's question. I interpret "[the SQL code will] be handed over to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" as "I will execute the SQL code in SSMS."

Answer (score 0):

We can separate the SQL queries with a semicolon. The following should work without any issues and you only need to make one call to your database connection.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp;CREATE TABLE #temp(ID INT);
```

This works on a local SQL Server instance:

```
Sub MyTest()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Set con = New Connection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    con.Open
    con.Execute "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp;Create table #temp(somecolumn int);"

    con.Close
End Sub
```